# Как программно проверить наличие PDF у пользователя

Tags: php, javascript, pdf

При нажатии кнопки "скачать" заданный PDF файл открывается для предпросмотра в браузере у посетителя. Но бывают случае когда у посетителя на компьютере не установлен PDF вместе с расширениями для браузера и соответственно PDF файл по нажатию на кнопку "скачать" сохраняется на компьютере вместо того что бы открыться для предпросмотра.

Могу ли я каким-то образом программно (php, js) проверить есть ли у пользователя на компьютере PDF и\или расширения для браузера которое позволяет открыть PDF для предпросмотра?

Comment: можно настроить браузер, чтобы он сразу скачивал, а не отображал на странице, поэтому толку от такой проверки нет

Comment: Открытие PDF в браузере - великое зло, учитывая количество дыр в продуктах Adobe.

Comment: @BOPOH у меня обратная ситуация, мне нужно что бы у тех, у кого есть pdf, он отображался в браузере, а у тех, у кого он не установлен, делался например редирект куда-то.

Comment: @DubovikYuriy настройками браузера можно отключить открытие в браузере. И лучше пользователям именно так браузер и настроить. Через JS можно попробовать запросить версию PDF-плагина, но оного плагина может не быть.

Comment: если по юзерагенту смотреть. в chrome и ff это встроенные плагины. а вот стоит ли adobe reader вы точно узнать не сможете

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов открытие pdf в браузере благое дело, учитывая что он давно уже стал открытым международным стандартом и для отображения можно использовать не только продукты adobe.

Comment: @AlexKrass зло это. Будет очередная дыра и простого захода на страницу хватит для выполнения произвольного кода. Запрос на сохранение PDF без явного указания со стороны юзера на его закачку может хоть как-то насторожить.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, это касается любого продукта, одна дыра и привет. Что теперь, компьютером не пользоваться? Кстати, браузеры Chrome и FF используют собственные разработки для отображения PDF, в частности PDF.js на HTML5 который не имеет никакого отношения к Adobe, их продуктам и их дырам.

Comment: Вы не можете проверить наличие плагина, но если уж очень сильно надо, то можете попробовать всегда использовать PDF.js для отображения без использования встроенных средств и не надеясь на них.